# Error while creating a GUI using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Whilst following through the Java in Easy Steps book I came across a error whilst creating my first GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    public Window() {
        super("Menu Window");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(pnl);
        setVisible(true) ;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main gui = new Window();
    }

}
```

And the error I get is:
'Error: Could not find or load main class main'

I am using Eclipse and this is the only thing that shows in the console.

[image]

Comment: If that's the exact error you got, then you tried to run the class as `main` when it's actually called `Main`.

Comment: That is the exact error I got, but in every case I've tried to run it as 'Main'. (I  believe)

Comment: But you should be trying to run it as `Main`, because that's the name of the class. (You specify the *class* name when you run it, and the JVM finds the `main` method, regardless of what the class is called.)

Comment: Yes, just then I meant to type 'Main', I have edited the comment, sorry. I may be making a stupid mistake, but I don't understand.

Comment: If you had tried to run it as `Main`, that's not the error you'd have got. I suggest you copy/paste the console output (including the command you're using to try to run it) into the question.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that your code doesn't even *compile*, so that's the first thing to fix. Next you need to change your launch configuration to run the `Main` class instead of the `main` class - I don't know how you created the launch configuration you're using, but it's not trying to launch the `Main` class... But really, don't try running code until it compiles.

Comment: Except from the answer i suggest you start learning `JavaFX` instead of `Swing` :)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor name should be the same as the class name (thus `Main` not `Window`), So we have:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    public Main() {//Watch this line carefully (Window changed to Main)
        super("Menu Window");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(pnl);
        setVisible(true) ;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main gui = new Main();//Watch here too
    }

}
```